# Carry we who die in battle

Tags: grammar, lyrics

A [song](http://www.darklyrics.com/lyrics/manowar/godsofwar.html#5) by the heavy metal band Manowar includes these lines:

> Carry we who die in battle
>
> Over land and sea

The "we" sounds wrong for me. I'd use "us" in this sentence. A quick google search didn't show any similar constructions with "we".

The "we" is a rather long-drawn sound in the song, so my best guess is that this wouldn't have worked with the sharp, short "us". But it is really completely wrong, or is there some way to justify this usage?

Note that all band members are born in the US, so they are native speakers.

Comment: And you think song lyrics (and even poetry) needs to be grammatically correct because ...?

Comment: Did I say it needs to be? I was asking if there is a construction that I don't know of that allows "we", not criticizing the song.

Comment: My comment was meant to suggest that there is a great deal of poetic license extended to lyrics. As the discussion below points out, it is not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to justify *we* there according to conventional rules if it is supposed to be the object of *carry*. It should be *us*:

> Carry us who die in battle over land and sea.

The reason why this writer mistakenly used *we* is probably as follows. The relative pronoun *who* is the subject of the relative clause, and *who* refers back to *we*, so a hint of "subjectivity" might cling to *we* as well, in the subconscious of the writer. But this is not done in conventional English.

What Janus says below could be another reason: there are some well known phrases where both the antecedent and the relative pronoun are the subjects of their respective clauses (main clause and relative clause), in which case *we who* would be correct.

Comment: And probably also because of familiar “we who” phrases (“We who are about to die salute you”, etc.).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But the *we* there is the subject of *salute*.

Comment: @bib Yes, in that phrase it is perfectly fine and grammatical—I meant that phrases like that (which are grammatical) can serve as the analogical basis for considering _we who_ a bit of an element to itself, and then start using that in places where it doesn’t belong, like here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Seductive, but like much that seeks to seduce, ...

Answer (score 3):

Song lyrics are subjective and more dependent on sound, scansion and rhythm than sense, let alone grammar; that is why ELU prefers not to deal with them. This specific question, though, is a reasonable one.  There is just one possibility. A Norse Valkyrie might sing the phrase to mean "We carry those who die in battle..."; if she can't get Wagner to write her theme tune, heavy metal would be a good second best.

(99.9% of English users would say "No, has to be *us*", and I've never properly encountered such a construction. But I recall a hymn starting "There is a book, who runs may read", and hearing a sermon about the grammar. Sadly, I wasn't listening closely enough to enligten you some thirty years later).

Answer (score -4):

It is grammatically correct. "We" is subject of the phrase "we who die in battle," and therefore is in the nominative case.

Comment: No. This is wrong. _We_ is not the subject of anything, and _we who die in battle_ is not a phrase. _Who_ is the subject of the relative clause _who die in battle_, with _we/us_ in the main clause being the antecedent to this subject.

Comment: You are correct. I should not have tossed off "phrase" quite so flippantly. In the strict sense of sentence diagramming, I was wrong. I used "phrase" in its everyday sense of a group of related words. Nevertheless, "we" is correct, though awkward. Compare with Kipling's famous "God, have mercy on such as we."

Comment: Fowler gives an example of the form

“Do not follow he who breaks the law.” 

saying (correctly) that the correct version is 

“Do not follow him who breaks the law.” The pronoun is apparently  being forced to do dual duty here, but takes the accusative case, being governed by the verb in the main clause. 'Carry we who die in battle', like 'Let he who is without sin cast the first stone', is incorrect. Think of 'Do not follow him (the one who breaks the law).'

Comment: @LindaStephenson: The reason why you can use *we* after *as* and *than* is that those words are conventionally said to be conjunctions, not prepositions, introducing (elliptical) clauses, which can have (nominative) subjects. So that is different.