# I am [who/whom] G-d made me

Tags: syntactic-analysis, linguistics, grammatical-case, whom, copular-verbs

Please fill in the blank with the correct word and explain your choice.

### *I am __ G-d made me.*

A. who

B. whom

---

Some people have suggested I elaborate on this question so here goes.

The above was not copied from any test. It is a question about basically two things: (1) whether an objective complement should be in the same case as the subject ("I" => "who") or as the object of the verb ("me" => "whom"); and (2) whether the verb to "make" [someone into something] should properly be considered a linking verb (~a form of "to be") (or, if not, whether this sentence has an implied nonfinite linking verb, and, if so, whether that would indeed exige the predicate nominative: "I am who G-d made me [to be]" => "I"? Or conceivably--since "me" becomes the subject[?] of the complement clause-- =>"me"?).

There are many other implications, just some of which are discussed [here](http://listserv.miamioh.edu/scripts/wa.exe?A3=ind1003&L=ATEG&E=quoted-printable&P=2225685&B=--&T=text%2Fplain;%20charset=us-ascii&header=1). It is a serious question that seems not to be addressed by any general overview of who/whom on this site.

There is another question about a similar construction, "[When to use what or who](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328326/when-to-use-what-or-who)", but the answers there don't address the topic of case.

My question may be addressed [in linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_case-marking) and may have different answers according to different [linguistic models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_role#Argument_structure_in_other_formal_approaches).

---

*Cf. "She is with whom I practice." "It is she I want to be like." "That's who I want to be like."*

> Related:
>
> [Which is grammatically correct: "Let he who..." or "Let him who..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42097/which-is-grammatically-correct-let-he-who-or-let-him-who/42099)
>
> [What rules make “Remember me, who am your friend” grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/what-rules-make-remember-me-who-am-your-friend-grammatical/28682#28682)
>
> https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48701/subject-of-imperatives-starting-with-let
>
> [Carry we who die in battle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192781/carry-we-who-die-in-battle/192787#192787)
>
> https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124307/is-i-killed-him-who-carried-a-gun-grammatically-correct
>
> [Issues with predicate nominative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140985/issues-with-predicate-nominative?noredirect=1&lq=1)
>
> https://www.theglobeandmail.com/opinion/let-he-who-is-a-latin-teacher-instruct-him/article747363/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use what or who](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328326/when-to-use-what-or-who) Also [What’s the rule for using “who” and “whom” correctly?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly)

Comment: Neither is correct. The relative pronoun should replace the subject or object in the relative clause but both are still there. It would be "I am who/whom G-d made" or "I am who made me".(who or whom both work; whom is hardly used at all in normal speech nowadays, but religious speech holds on to some archaism me like 'whom'.

Comment: I've nominated [one of the very first questions on the site](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly) as the duplicate, because it shows how to determine which pronoun to use, and thereby demonstrates that the sentence is ungrammatical to start with.

Comment: "X is who Y made Z" not grammatical.
"Adjective is how Y made Z" grammatical (from "Y made Z Adjective")
"X is who/whom Y loves" (from "Y loves X")
"Queen is ..." is the first pattern which is ungrammatical. We disagree on the grammaticality of the first pattern. [Andrew Leach](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/335453/i-am-who-whom-g-d-made-me?noredirect=1#comment768224_335455) agrees with me.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Are you suggesting that *who* must be a subject or object and that *whom* must be an object?

Comment: @Araucaria Yes. *Whom* must be an object; that is, it cannot be a subject. That is, if you determine that the relative pronoun **is** a subject, it cannot be *whom.* But the thing with the example sentence in the question is that neither is right. The sentence is not a sentence.

Comment: @AndrewLeach There's examples enough from printed books and it makes perfect sense to me. The idea that "whom" must be an object is misguided. If you think about it, those answers say that there's an equivalence between "he/him" etc. This isn't exactly true, because it depends on whether we're talking interrogative of relative "who(m)" and many other things. But just looking at "he/him" etc, it becomes very clear that "him" is the default and "he" is normally only used for subjects (although occasionally by a minority of speakers also for subject oriented predicative complements).

Comment: @AndrewLeach So for example in: "A: Who's he? B: Who, *him*?" the word *him* is not an object. The rule for so-called object pronouns is that they are used whenever a pronoun is not a subject of a tensed verb, not that they are used only when they are objects.

Comment: @Araucaria What I commented was that *whom* must be an object; I said nothing about *him* -- apart from in [a comment below](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/335453/i-am-who-whom-g-d-made-me?noredirect=1#comment778647_337882). However the fact remains that in the question here, **neither option is correct because the sentence is not a sentence in either case.**

Comment: @AndrewLeach Hmm, but  that's not correct. "Whom" need not be an object. For example it can be the complement of a preposition. Do you have any vetted grammar sources backing up that object claim? Also, I've just given you a load of examples from printed books, so I don't see how you can say that it "isn't a sentence"?

Comment: Just because someone has printed an ungrammatical sentence doesn't make it grammatical. It may be intelligible, and "This is who God made me" is concise and understandable, but I defy even you to parse it. However, neither example contradicts my assertion that *whom* must be an object and cannot be a subject (because they don't use *whom*). Complements of prepositions are a good example of cases actually appearing in English, which is generally said not to have them, or at least not to be concerned about them.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It's a sentence with a fused relative clause construction (aka *free relative*) functioning as Predicative Complement of the verb *MAKE*. Free relatives often require *-ever* to be cliticised onto the relative pronoun. Not always when they are predicative complements, however.

Comment: I think I feel a question coming on. The *me* seems superfluous and it is that which jars into ungrammaticality.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Maybe read the link in the OP; it seems to me to refute your assertion pretty thoroughly (although I may have misunderstood something). Also, I hope you or another moderator will consider reinstating the many deleted comments from earlier. Questions that were cleared up then are now being asked again.

Comment: @SAH Comments were deleted because all the discussion ought to have been put into a couple of answers which expressed their differing points of view on the grammacality of the given sentence.

Comment: @KitZFox The content of those comments would not have been answers to the question, for my question was not "Is this sentence grammatical?" These comments were clearly acceptable according to the Stackexchange standards outlined here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work . We are now at a loss. I will continue to ask for moderators' attention

Comment: I think "That is whom I want to be like" would be the prescribed version of that last sentence, but as F.E. points out in the answer to the linked question, it doesn't always seem like the prescriptive rules get it right in this area.

Comment: @sumelic Why? And do you think that example is substantially different from "I am who(m) G-d made me"? Thanks as always

Comment: Yes, it does seem different to me. In "I am [whom _ made me]", "whom" is an object complement, but in "That's [who I want to be like]", "who" is an outright object of the preposition "like", and as an object, I think the prescriptive rules fairly clearly state that it "should" be *whom.* That 'should' is in apostrophes based on F.E.'s statement that "obviously that 'rule' isn't so good. For instance, 'Whomever he marries will have to be very tolerant' (same as [18.iii] in *CGEL*) doesn't sound too smooth and *is at best very questionable.*" https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166847

Comment: I think "That's whom I want to be like" sounds particularly questionable because it lacks fronting (which seems to be impossible with "be like"--"that is like whom I want to be"), and in general the "That's who..." construction doesn't seem to belong to a formal register of speech (I would expect instead something like "It is he/she whom I want to be like").

Comment: @sumelic But doesn't that contradict your comment on my answer here? https://english.stackexchange.com/a/341413/9819

Comment: @SAH: Which part do you think has a contradiction?

Comment: @sumelic There you seem to say that the authorities would favor "Give it to him who is happy"; here you suggest they'd endorse "That is whom I want to be like." In the latter example, the pronoun's case is determined by its function in the embedded clause. In the former, it seems to be determined by its function in the matrix clause. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SAH: The rule about going with the embedded clause role over the matrix clause role only applies to relative pronouns, not personal pronouns like *him/he.* I think it's actually arguable whether "him" in that sentence should even be considered part of the embedded clause at all (obviously, people seem to have some kind of intuition that it is related, but I mean from a prescriptive perspective this intuition might be considered erroneous: the structure is "Give it **to (him** [who is happy])" not "*Give it to ([**he who] is** happy)").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64800/discussion-between-sumelic-and-sah).

Comment: The sentence is ungrammatical. The question of *who* vs. *whom* has been beaten to death already.

Comment: @Kris: Why is it ungrammatical? I've posted a separate question about that topic, and I'd appreciate an answer:  [Why do so many people find “I am who(m) God made me” unacceptable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447473)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["I didn't realize it was him."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121198/i-didnt-realize-it-was-him)

Answer (score 8):

- If I could choose ***neither***, I would, since I'm not sure if the sentence is grammatical (I have asked a separate question about that here: [Is "I am who(m) God made me" grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447473/is-i-am-whom-god-made-me-grammatical)).
- If I had to choose one and I was allowed to choose based on my own preferences, I would choose ***who*** since, as many posts on this site explain, "whom" often sounds stuffy or pedantic.
- But if I had to choose one based on what I think fits best with *prescriptive* grammar, I would choose ***whom***.

---

This isn't a complete answer, so much as a summary of what I've discovered while researching this question. I hope some syntax expert will post a more a definitive answer.

### Syntax: the "object complement"

In sentences of the form "[God] [made] [me] [a man]," "God" is the subject, "made" is the verb, and "me" is the object of the verb. The phrase "a man," rather than being an object, serves the role of what is called an "[object complement](http://www.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/objects.htm)."

### The grammatical case of the object complement

This is tricky to ascertain, since most sentences with a pronoun in this position sound very awkward and unnatural ("God made me her"?/"God made me she"?).

However, I think there are several fairly strong arguments for it being in the objective case.

For one thing, I was able to find one fairly common expression that uses this structure with an objective-case pronoun as the object complement: "[what makes me me](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=what%20makes%20me%20me&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)" and variations on this phrase. As far as I can tell, no one say "what makes me I," and my intuition tells me that this would be ungrammatical.

Unfortunately, this is not a foolproof argument because online examples that are similar to this often show some odd punctuation that casts doubt on the role of the pronoun here. Often there is a comma or ellipsis before the pronoun: "[What made me, me](https://books.google.com/books?id=gdysqalK2iQC&pg=PA69&dq=%22made%20me%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG3oWxz-zNAhVBNiYKHa7mAAcQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22made%20me%20me%22&f=false)", "[everything that made me ... me](https://books.google.com/books?id=98p0azZ2xrUC&pg=PA56&dq=%22made%20me%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG3oWxz-zNAhVBNiYKHa7mAAcQ6AEIPzAG#v=onepage&q=%22made%20me%20me%22&f=false)". In contrast, a comma would be ungrammatical in "God made me, a man." This might be a sign that these phrases have different grammatical structures.

Sometimes, what appears to be the object pronoun is capitalized or put in quotation marks: "[What events in my life had made me, Me?](https://books.google.com/books?id=FCvebWHTBHwC&pg=PA24&dq=%22made%20me%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG3oWxz-zNAhVBNiYKHa7mAAcQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=%22made%20me%20me%22&f=false)", "[the things that made me 'me'](https://books.google.com/books?id=dDg1AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT47&dq=%22made%20me%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG3oWxz-zNAhVBNiYKHa7mAAcQ6AEIRTAH#v=onepage&q=%22made%20me%20me%22&f=false) ". This odd treatment almost suggests the word "me" in this expression is being treated as a noun rather than a pronoun, and in that case it would not inflect for case and would be useless as evidence for the "who"/"whom" rule. (A parallel case: we say "[The Me I Want to Be](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/031034056X)", not "The I I want to Be," but prescriptive grammar still prescribes the nominative form in the phrase "who I want to be.")

But, I think there are also theoretical arguments that suggest the object complement is in the objective case (or at least, that it "should" be in prescriptivist grammar). The most straightforward is that it's a *complement,* and prescriptivists often value arguments like "complements should match the case of their referent." That's the whole foundation of the argument for saying "It is I" rather than "It is me."

From a more descriptive viewpoint, I have read that the "objective" case or pronouns is generally less marked in modern English, which I think means that phrases tend to default to that unless explicitly assigned to the nominative case by a rule. However, the objective case of "whom" is an exception since it basically only occurs in educated constructions that have to be explicitly taught. Some linguists argue that the rules for using "whom" have actually become distinct in the modern language from the rest of the English case system. (Some papers I found about this that I still have to finish going through: [The Who/Whom Puzzle: On The Preservation Of An Archaic Feature](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1006322600501), [Whom and the English Case System](http://academics.utep.edu/Portals/878/papers/whom_paper_vancouver.pdf)).

### Is it grammatical to replace the object complement with a pronoun?

I'm not sure if it's grammatical to replace this element of the sentence with a fronted relative pronoun. (I believe "who" or "whom" in this context would be a relative pronoun, although I'm not sure: it's possible it would be an interrogative). I'm currently trying to research this.

There are some examples of sentences with object complements here: http://www.englishgrammar.org/object-complement/

> - They elected Martin their president.
> - They named the boy Christopher.

I don't get great results when I try to modify them to use the pronoun "what":

- *What they elected Martin was their president.
- ?What they named Christopher was the boy.
- ?What they named the boy was Christopher.

These all seem awkward to me, although Mitch and Araucaria have left comments indicating that "What they named the boy was Christopher" seems OK to them. The comments that used to exist below this question indicate that many people think "I am who(m) G-d made me" sounds ungrammatical, although I have not found any source that explains why it would be.

Araucaria also found some real-life examples of "I am/ This is who God made me" that I think are worth listing in an answer:

- *[Connected: You and God in the Psalms](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lT9tAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA175&dq=%22who%20God%20made%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBwPCi0oTOAhVFJcAKHWAtA1gQ6AEIUDAJ#v=onepage&q=%22who%20God%20made%20me%22&f=false),* by Peter Wallace
- *[God, Sex, and Politics: Homosexuality and Everyday Theologies](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8GxgROaV5y0C&pg=PA212&dq=%22who%20God%20made%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE8NfV0oTOAhWpKsAKHUFUBck4ChDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=%22who%20God%20made%20me%22&f=false),* by Dawne Moon

### According to typical prescriptive rules, the pronoun's role in the matrix clause shouldn't affect its form

The matrix clause (or main clause) in this example is "I am __." In general, the choice of "who" or "whom" is not affected by the pronoun's role in the matrix clause, only by its role in the embedded clause. So the prescriptivist rule about using the nominative form of a pronoun after "I am" should be irrelevant. (A similar example is discussed in this following question: [Who vs. whom in complex sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202650/who-vs-whom-in-complex-sentences)—"I gave the prize to whoever deserved it most" is correct, even though we would say "I gave the prize to him/her," because the case is determined by the embedded clause "deserved it most" and we we would say "He/She deserved it most.") The following questions are also relevant: [Can a phrase be the object of a clause and how would its subject change?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174671/can-a-phrase-be-the-object-of-a-clause-and-how-would-its-subject-change),  ["I give it to him who came first" vs. "to he who came first"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62385/i-give-it-to-him-who-came-first-vs-to-he-who-came-first), [Which is grammatically correct: "Let he who..." or "Let him who..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42097/which-is-grammatically-correct-let-he-who-or-let-him-who).

For some speakers, there are additional complications in phrases such as "[the person whom the police thought was responsible](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=10398)," but as Geoffrey K. Pullum explains in the linked article, the use of *whom* in this context is generally considered incorrect by prescriptivists.

A caveat: F.E.'s answer to the following question is also relevant, and points out that in real English usage (as opposed to the rules of prescriptivists), "fused relative" constructions like this with clashing case requirements may be avoided:
["Put me in touch with whomever created it"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166847/put-me-in-touch-with-whomever-created-it)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_(pronoun)#Ambiguous_cases) cites an interesting passage from "The Distribution of Pronoun Case Forms in English", by Heidi Quinn, that indicates that in a similar construction in Old English (the "argument relative"), the case of the *wh*-pronoun was based on its role in the matrix clause.

> For example, the *wh*-pronoun *wam* functions as the subject of the relative clause in (65), but the relative itself functions as the object of the matrix preposition *to.* Since the matrix clause always wins out over the relative-internal clause, the *wh*-pronoun in (65) surfaces as the objective form *wam*, rather than as the nominative form *hwa*.

(p. 331)

Unfortunately, the page with the relevant sentence was not visible in the Google Books, but I found what seems to be the same example in a PDF of Quinn's thesis:

```
Ðe holi gost ... hine dealeð to [wam him beoð lofue]
the holy ghost ...  3sgM.ACC gives to wh.OBJ 3sgM.OBJ is pleasing
'The holy ghost ... gives it to whomever is pleasing to him.'

(Layamon (Otho) 9081) [AlIen 1980: 208]
```

I'm not actually sure based on this example if this construction is really analogous to the modern English construction, but it's interesting nevertheless. You can see more discussion on the [Wikipedia talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AWho_(pronoun)#Disruptive_reversions_by_an_anonymous_editor).

Quinn also mentions the typically limited distribution of *who(m)* in free relatives that Peter Shor mentioned in his answer:

> In Modern English free relatives, the complex *wh*-forms *whoever, whomever, whoso(ever),* and *whomsoever* tend to be favoured over the simplex forms *who* and *whom* (cf. Jespersen 1949[1927]:62, Baker 1995:210f), except when the relative clause involves VP ellipsis (69) or Null Complement Anaphora (70).

([p. 333](https://books.google.com/books?id=gjRV0gU1W3oC&pg=PA333#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Comment: *President* won't work because it's a bare role NP. "What they named Christopher was the boy" doesn't seem to bear a good relation to the original, it seems to me . "What they named the boy was Christopher" seems ok to me ...  (but grammaticality is in the ear of the beholder, no doubt!)

Comment: @Araucaria and @ sumelic, Thank you so much for championing my question, and for your serious efforts toward finding the answer.

Comment: @Sumelic Do you have any way of retrieving and adding the info you originally posted as comments on the OP? There, you said that the pronoun almost certainly (according to the prescriptive authorities) takes case according to its position in the embedded clause. I believed you, and would love to see that information in this answer, especially if you have a source :)

Comment: "What they named the boy was Christopher." sounds fine to me. Also "Christopher was what they named the boy" is fine too.

Comment: @sumelic I'm still mulling the details of this reply.  Please tell me how it would sound if we conceived the original sentence instead as this ellipsis, for: "I am _he_, whom God made me."

Comment: @H.David: "he" sounds fine in that context. Compare the example in SAH's answer: "Give it to **who**ever is happy" is correct, but so is "Give it to **him** who is happy."

Comment: possibly related: [He must decide who/whom to be. Which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294223)

Answer (score 5):

TL:DR. Just use *who*. You've already dispensed with traditional grammar by using *who(m)* instead of *who(m)ever*; why start paying attention to antiquated rules at this point?

And the detailed explanation:

In

> I am who(m) God made me,

the pronoun *who(m)* is serving as both the subject complement of the verb *am* and the object of *made*. This is a *fused relative clause*, and traditionally (say early 20th century English) this is not allowed; you need to use *who(m)ever* for pronouns that serve two different roles. [See this languagelog post](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002690.html).

For *who(m)ever* in fused relatives, the pronoun should agree with its role in the dependent clause. [See reference.](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoever.asp) Thus, traditionally the sentence should read

> I am whomever God made me.

However, recently *who* has been replacing *who(m)ever* in fused relative clauses. Half the time I am waiting in lines, I hear

> I can help who's next.

(And half the time I still hear *whoever*.)

So should you apply the same rules you use for *who(m)ever* to *who(m)* in fused relative clauses?

Since replacing *who(m)ever* with *who* is a new innovation, and using *who* instead of *whom* (except after prepositions) is a slightly less new innovation, to me using *whom* in

> ? I am whom God made me

sounds wrong – if you're going to dispense with traditional grammar for the fused relative clause, maybe you should also dispense with traditional grammar for *who/whom*, and just say

> I am who God made me.

That's my gut feeling; I don't have any references supporting this view.

What about other situations? The simplest solution is just to use *who* all the time in fused relative clauses. You should certainly use *who* in clauses like

> I will give this to who wants it,

since *whom* sounds terrible as the subject of a relative clause. But what about

> I will give this to who(m) it fits,

where the pronoun follows a preposition and is the object of the relative clause. To my ear, the formal *whom* used in this sentence which really should have *whomever* is jarring, and *who* actually sounds better.

Answer (score 2):

If one uses the grammatical rule:

> Rule. Use this he/him method to decide whether who or whom is correct:
>
> he = who
> him = whom
>
> Examples:
> Who/Whom wrote the letter?
> He wrote the letter.
> Therefore, who is correct.
>
> [For] who/whom should I vote?
> Should I vote for him? Therefore, whom is correct.

([Grammarbook.com](http://m.grammarbook.com/grammar-rules/who-vs-whom.aspx))

If one then follows this rule through, God made *him* not he, therefore:
I am **whom** God made me.

Comment: But, "I am he".

Comment: Very good point, perhaps I am mistaken then; further research needed

Comment: Really this is all beyond me. Once grammar terms come out I am lost.

Comment: "I am he" is fine: the verb *be* **grammatically** doesn't take an object; it's a copula. **Idiomatically,** the object form of pronouns is used "That's me!"

Answer (score 0):

I think the sentence itself is incorrect since it's a relative clause and relative clauses can't end in pronouns which relates to the same as the relative pronoun does, for example we can't say ( the man whom I helped him) we should say ( the man whom I helped) and your sentence should be like that ( I am whom God made) not ( I am whom God made me). And the suitable pronoun is (whom) in your sentence because the case is objective one ....

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current conclusion, which is in keeping with @[sumelic's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/337921/98198), and with a lemma in @[Peter Shor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/335453/i-am-who-whom-g-d-made-me/395986#395986)'s. (It may be worth noting that all the major answers so far--at least those which allow the sentence can be analyzed--have come down on the side of "whom." [Yes, even Peter Shor's, in my view.]  [Sumelic's comment on my answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/335453/i-am-who-whom-g-d-made-me/341413#341413) casts, however, some doubt.])

> It's "whom,"
>
> because the whole noun phrase
>
> > whom G-d made me
>
> is the predicate nominative of the sentence. Because the whole noun
>   phrase functions as a nominative, the "who[m]" itself doesn't need to
>   be nominative. It can do what it is supposed to do as an objective
>   complement in the phrase; that is, be accusative. => whom

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the sentence in the original question is stilted and unidiomatic. The *me* in *“I am who/whom G_d made me”* is redundant. Leave out the object pronoun and the sentence improves considerably.

My answer will be short and sweet. The words in capital letters are quoted verbatim

> And God said unto Moses, **I AM THAT I AM**: and he said, Thus shalt thou say unto the children of Israel, I AM hath sent me unto you.

*[King James Bible](http://biblehub.com/exodus/3-14.htm)*

ergo

> I am **that** which God made

Answer (score -1):

The object case is used after a transitive verb.  After a verb of being, such as in the example, the subject case is used.  That would make, "I am who," correct.

This seems to be to be the whole explanation:
http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/it-is-i-versus-it-is-me

Comment: The nominative case is used for the complement of a verb of being that has a nominative subject. But in this sentence, the pronoun "who(m)" is not the complement of the verb "am"; it is the complement of the object of the relative clause. The complement of "am" is the entire relative clause "who(m) God made me".

Comment: While you may be right, this explanation is much too short. In this sentence, *who* serves as both the subject complement of *am* and the object of *made*. So should it be *who* or *whom*? For *whoever/whomever*, it's the dependent clause that determines the grammar, so it should be *I am whomever God made me*. [See reference](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoever.asp).

Comment: So do you think *"I can serve who's next"* is grammatical? Or should it be *"I can serve whom's next"*?

Comment: @sumelic,  I totally misread the question.  Should I delete the answer?

Answer (score -1):

I am *who* God made me (to be).

Notice I have added a part that can be said to have been elided. The verb *be* is often elided and the sentence sounds better without it being elided.

As far as *who*, and the "rules," well, frankly in case of pronouns, including who/whom, native speakers (per descriptive grammar) follow **only one rule consistently**: use whatever sounds best/comes natural. Thus: *Who is at the door?* The answer is *It's me*, and only prescriptive grammarians will insist doggedly on *It's I* even though this is based on a rule derived from Latin.

Answer (score -3):

I have finally satisfied myself with an answer to this question. It's "whom," from the fact that we know this is correct:

> "Give it to he who is happy."

...The above example illustrates an interesting point. "They" are wise to obfuscate causality in their statement of the rule that "a relative pronoun [such as "who(m)"] always agrees in number and person with its antecedent"--because, surprisingly enough, the causality seems to work backwards: the gender, number, and case of the antecedent *follow* those of the subsequent relative pronoun.

In other words, you (1) start with the embedded clause--the immediate environs of the relative pronoun--to find out what gender/number/case *it* must take, and then you (2) make the relative pronoun's antecedent match it.

(All this analysis I am deriving from the knowledge that "Give it to he who is happy" is correct.)

I'm not sure how to apply Step Two to the given sentence ("I am [who/whom] G-d made me")--maybe that's proof that this sentence is ungrammatical after all. But we can easily complete Step One, which yields "whom."

> I am whom G-d made me
>
> Me is whom G-d made me
>
> Whom G-d made me is me

Comment: My understanding is that "give it to he who is happy" is actually not generally considered "correct" (it's relatively commonly seen, but not standard). See the answers to the following questions: [“I give it to him who came first” vs. “to he who came first”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62385), [Which is grammatically correct: “Let he who…” or “Let him who…”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42097)

Comment: @sumelic Oh, no!

Comment: I just realized that my answer doesn't at all address the issue of whether "to make [someone] [something]" could be a linking verb. This question is still anyone's game